# Reversing letters in a string (but not non-letters) while keeping the original casing

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example the sentence:

```
'God bless our brave Confederates, Lord!'
```

...should be:

```
'Dro lseta red efnoc Evarbruossel, Bdog!'
```

My code is currently:

```
def reversing(sentence):
    code = []
    for l1, l2 in zip(sentence, sentence[::-1]):
        if l1.isalpha() and l2.isalpha():
            l2 = l2.upper() if l1.isupper() else l2.lower()
        code.append(l2)
    return ''.join(code)
```

But it isn't quite right:

```
>>> reversing('God bless our brave Confederates, Lord!')
'!drol ,setaredefnoc Evarb ruo sselB doG'
```

Comment: Should the uppercases be absolutely respected?

Comment: Yes for example if the first letter in the original sentence is uppercase, than the first letter in the reversed sentence must also be uppercased and same goes for lowercases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple stack and queue based solution

```
a= 'God bless our brave Confederates, Lord!'

stack=[] # to keep characters
queue=[] # to keep special chars
for i in a:
    if i.isalpha():
        stack.append(i)
    else:
        queue.append(i)
```

Iterate over original string to find and check if char is upper and it is not special char

```
string=''
for i in a:  
    if i.isalpha():
        if i.isupper():
            string += stack.pop(-1).upper() # change from lower to upper char based on original string
        else:
            string += stack.pop(-1).lower()
    else:
        string += queue.pop(0)
print(string)
```

Output

```
'Dro Lseta red efnoC Evarbruossel, Bdog!'
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution produces the desired effect, but it does have a downside of iterating twice over the same list. If the practical application for this will have long inputs, then this solution will not be the best from an execution time perspective.

```py
def reversing(sentence):
    parts = list(sentence)
    code = []

    # first iteration reverses only the letters
    for enum, value in enumerate(parts):
        character = sentence[-1 - enum].lower()

        if character.isalpha():
            code.append(character)

    # second iteration formats and inserts non-letters
    for enum, value in enumerate(parts):
        if value.isalpha() and value.isupper():
            code[enum] = code[enum].upper()
        elif not value.isalpha():
            code.insert(enum, value)

    return ''.join(code)
```

Comment: @BlueSheepToken sounds good. I have updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks!